# React stateless functional component to class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Can you help me in changing this React stateless functional component to React class based component including the withRouter and history object as given?

```
const Menu = withRouter(({history}) => (
   <AppBar>

   </AppBar>
))
export default Menu
```

Comment: Why not use [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)?

Comment: Could you explain it more please? how can i solve this by using react hooks?

Comment: [Converting React function component to class component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43695583/1218980)

Comment: I can not use react hooks, i am using an older version of react in my project and i cant update it due to some other dependency issues

Comment: [Using React Router withRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39174814/1218980)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // you can use this.props.history anywhere in the class
    const { history } = this.props;
    return <AppBar>...</AppBar>
  }
}

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create your class component and then, create a constructor for the class. You can then define the states required inside the constructor, something like this-

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   SomeVar: xyz,
   AnotherVar: undefined
  }
 }

 render() {
  return withRouter(({history}) => (
   <AppBar> </AppBar>
  ));
 }
}
```

Comment: Was it helpful. Please let me know.